# Why is this SSL certificate not installed correctly?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have two domain hosted on Google App Engine which use the same SSL certificate:

- https://test.moveapp.co/
- https://pay.moveapp.co/

They both show the SSL certificate as working in the browsers I tested (Chrome, Safari, Firefox). However this Symantec tools claims that the "pay.moveapp.co" certificate is not installed correctly:

https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/

What is going on? It doesn't give any helpful information. It says an intermediate certificate is missing, but this is false, and it is the same certificate on both domains.

Comment: you do understand, that because you are bought from Symantec, your SSL will be un-trusted in March 2018 ?

Comment: It says _certificate installed correctly_ when I try it for both domains!

Answer (score 2):

Both certificates are installed correctly.

Never used Symantec, but they have problems with their own SSL authority so I would never relie to them.

Easiest standalone check would be with `curl` (yes, it is very very strict and picky).

Another way is to use https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you use appengine apps, then a good way to enable SSL is to use the [builtin Letsencrypt certificates](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-managed-SSL-for-Google-App-Engine.html). You only need to verify your domain with Google webmaster tools and then enabling SSL is completely painless.